# Does Jenkins take care of Daylight saving?

Tags: jenkins

I changed Jenkins configuration file i.e. jenkins.xml located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.xml`  with: user timezone = America/Chicago

```xml
<executable>%BASE%\jre\bin\java</executable>
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Duser.timezone="America/Chicago" 
  -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle 
  -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080</arguments>
```

I can see time changed to CDT.

My question is after daylight saving changes, do I still have to change timezone? Or will jenkins take care of Day light saving since timezone is set to America/Chicago?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is of any help but there is this plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Timestamp+Plugin

Comment: Thank you, it did.